# Font Awesome icon not showing on IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, mime-types, font-awesome

Font Awesome icons are not showing on IE7. They do on IE8, IE9, FF and Chrome.

Example HTML:

```
<span rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Click to add question to favorites">
    <i class="icon-star-empty"></i>
</span>
```

Files included:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
```

Request to .woff:

```
Request: 
URL:http://example.com/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff

Response:
Accept-Ranges:bytes 
Connection:Keep-Alive 
Content-Length:41752
Content-Type:application/octet-stream 
Date:Tue, 11 Dec 2012 11:31:51 GMT 
ETag:"4095e-a318-4cf1d75fb20dd" 
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Last-Modified:Thu, 22 Nov 2012 23:02:27 GMT Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

I've configured this on Apache's /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf (and restarted Apache):

```
AddType application/octet-stream .woff
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration was correct after all. For some reason font-awesome-ie7.css wasn't loading correctly. After making sure that this file was loading, everything worked.

Comment: this was very helpul for me...Thank a lot @martincho

Answer (score 16):

Quick update to this thread.

FontAwesome no longer supports IE7, but if you're in the unfortunate situation where you need to support it because you need to support proprietary software, whos name I shall not mention, that includes it as its only browser, and refuses to upgrade even though, at the time of this post, IE8 has been out for nearly 4 years and we are now on IE11, then do as I did:

1. Download the ie7.min.css file and add the section as indicated in the answer above:
2. Open the ie7.min.css file and change all the ".icon-" to ".fa-", since FontAwesome has changed its naming conventions.

This will get you support on about 95% of the icons for the FA 4.0.3 (newly introduced fonts won't be supported on the old ie7.min.css file.

Comment: Support was removed in Font Awesome 4.0.0, so the latest version of the ie file is in the latest 3.x release: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/v3.2.1/css

Comment: The css expressions used in that file dont work in ie11's compatibility mode, due to a bug https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/798953/ie11-bug-expression-of-css-is-not-enabled-in-compatibility-mode-with-internet-zone . So go and buy an old computer with ie7 on it.

Comment: Sorry, the above was unclear. They didnt work for me in *emulation mode* in ie11. I was trying to emulate ie7, ofcourse. YMMV.

Comment: You can always use the regular font file (otf) and uplaod it to font squirrels web font generator to create the .eot files needed for IE6,7. No need to stick to old versions of FA.

Comment: @iroybot: how to do that?

Comment: as I said it: go to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator upload the latest otf and generate the web fonts. make sure to tick the dot option.

Answer (score 8):

Better use the IE7 conditional comment, so the file gets loaded in IE7 only. (taken from the [Fontawesome example](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/))

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/css/your-icons.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/css/your-icons-ie7.min.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: from where to download your-icons-ie7.min.css file?

Comment: the name is just an example. if you want to use Font Awesome, go to https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ and click download.
as mentioned in the comments here the IE7 was supported until v3 so if you want a IE7 css for Font awesome 4.4 you will need to write it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to support IE7 even for new icons.

First download this as base.
https://gist.github.com/dorajistyle/7461853

Then if any icon is missing go that icon in the iconlist. For example the fa-balance-scale that is new.
http://fontawesome.io/icon/balance-scale/

There you'll see that the unicode char is f24e

Then add this to the font-awesome-ie7.min.css in the end

```
.fa-balance-scale {
    *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = 
'&#xf24e;');
}
```

Repeat for any icons you're using